# When to use double-t ("-tt-"), when to use a single-t ("-t-") in spellings?

Tags: orthography

I have the following questions:

1. Why do words like "Committee" have a double-t ("-tt-") while words like "satisfy" have a single-t ("-t-")?
2. Is there a general rule concerning when should one use a double-t ("-tt-") and when should a single-t ("-t-") be used?

Comment: There is no general rule, unfortunately. There are multiple rules, of varying levels of generality, dependent on multiple factors, and usually with multiple exceptions. Here are some relevant questions: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-consonant?sort=frequent&pageSize=50

Comment: Here is a page with some information about general tendencies: http://usefulenglish.ru/writing/double-consonants

Comment: As mentioned in the link from @sumelic, check the syllables of [*satisfy*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=satisfy) vs. [*committee*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=committee). For *committee*, both letters m and t follow this rule.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there one P in "hoping" and two P's in "hopping"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/248080/why-is-there-one-p-in-hoping-and-two-ps-in-hopping)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid, English Learner, that like most of English spelling, the rule is "use -tt- in words that have -tt- and use -t- in words that have -t-".

I know that's unhelpful, but there are no general rules.

There are partial rules for specific cases (for example, you often double the 't' when adding suffixes like '-ing' and '-ed' "hitting", "plotted"; but even that is not invariable, eg "editing), but that's all.

Your particular examples are both derived from Latin, and reflect a real difference in the way the Latin words were written, and, probably, how they were pronounced. ("committee" is from a Latin word "committo") But you would need to know Latin to know that. In English, I'm afraid you just have to learn that one has one 't' and the other has two.

**Edited** to correct "spelt" to "pronounced".

Comment: You mean "pronounced" instead of "spelt"? Some varieties of Italian still have short and long consonants, so "tt" probably was pronounced differently from "t" in Latin.

Comment: @PeterShor Are there even any (major) varieties of Italian that _don’t_ retain contrastive consonant length?

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer:

When the **
** is a part of [stressed syllable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)), it *often* gets doubled (it's mostly true for verbs).

You can't tell which syllables are stressed by looking at the spelling. However, most dictionaries give [phonetic transcription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_transcription) of words. You'll notice that there's a [diacritic mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) (**'**) in the transcription, the syllable following that mark is stressed/ accented.

**OP's examples:**

- Committee /kə**ˈ**mɪt.i/ - The t gets doubled because it's a part of stressed syllable.
- Satisfy /ˈsæt.ɪs.faɪ/ - The t does not get doubled because it's a part of unstressed syllable.

## Explanation:

**✴** When the **t** is a part of *stressed syllable* and is preceded by a *vowel*, it often gets doubled in *present participle* and *past participle*.

**Examples:** *Submit* has two syllables, the **t** is a part of the second syllable which is stressed so it gets doubled in present participle and past participle.

Submit /səbˈmɪt/ -> submi**tt**ing, submi**tt**ed.

Similarly, *admit* has two syllables in which the second one is stressed and the **t** is a part of second syllable so it gets doubled in present participle and past participle.

Admit /ədˈmɪt/ -> admi**tt**ing, admi**tt**ed.

---

**✴** When the t is a part of *unstressed* syllable, it does not get doubled in present participle and past participle.

**Examples:** *Elicit* has three syllables. The **t** is a part of *unstressed syllable* so it does not get doubled.

Elicit /iˈlɪs.ɪt/ -> elici**t**ing, elici**t**ed.

Similarly, *interpret* has three syllables. Stress is on the second syllable and the **t** is a part of the unstressed syllable so it does not get doubled in present participle and past participle.

Interpret /ɪnˈtɜː.prɪt/ -> interpre**t**ing, interpre**t**ed.

---

**✴** Monosyllabic verbs that end with t can have **-tt-** or **-t-**, it depends on the preceding letter.

**1.** If the t is preceded by a vowel, the t often gets doubled in present and past participle.

**Examples:**

- Spot /spɒt/ -> spo**tt**ed, spo**tt**ing.
- Fit /fɪt/ -> fi**tt**ed, fi**tt**ing.
- Jot /dʒɒt/ -> jo**tt**ed, jo**tt**ing etc.

**2.** If a *consonant* precedes the **t** in monosyllabic word, the t does not often get doubled in present participle and past participle.

**Examples:**

- Act /ækt/ -> a**ct**ed, a**ct**ing.
- Want /wɒnt/ -> wa**nt**ed
- Jolt /dʒəʊlt/ -> jo**lt**ed, jo**lt**ing etc.

---

**✴** Multisyllabic verbs in which the t is preceded by a *consonant sound* have **-t-** in their present participle and past participle.

**Examples:**

- Accept /əkˈsept/ -> acce**pt**ed, acce**pt**ing.
- Attempt /əˈtempt/ -> attem**pt**ed.
- Interact /ˌɪn.təˈrækt/ -> intera**ct**ed, intera**ct**ing etc.

For more details, read **[this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/248082/106592)** answer.